# Using a wav file to make my Python ml code speak in a specifically trained voice model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, voice

I recently trained my own voice model using Tensorflow and Tacotron and it produced a trained .wav file which I want to implement into my ai to give him a custom voice. This is the code I have now for the voice.

```
from datetime import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import webbrowser
import wikipedia
import wolframalpha

from logging import exception
# speech engine intialisation
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
activationWord = 'ideon'


def speak(text, rate=120):
    engine.setProperty('rate', rate)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

This works but only with 2 options for the voice and no way to add my custom voice.

Comment: Can you add some detail in this about what you have tried to add more voices? It looks like `engine.setProperty('voice',...)` is the start of that. What part of the documentation are you looking at, for Tensorflow or Tacotron?

Comment: So I'm sorry Im relatively new to all this.. so this is my original code just to test my ai but I now have a .wav file I am trying to make as my voice that I've trained using tacotron 2 and tenserflow. I simply can't  figure out what code I should be using to do this, I hope this makes sense

Comment: I get what I'm trying to do is export a voice model into my ai code so this new model or in this case wav file will take over for the current voice I have now.